# re-SSH to a machine after remote reboot

Tags: bash, ssh, sh

I'm changing some configuration settings on a remote machine using SSH. To apply these configurations, I need to reboot. Afterwards, I need to reconnect again to make some more configuration changes. For example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ssh <host> 'sh -s' < first-step.sh
# Wait for system to reboot...
rebooted=false
while [[ "$rebooted" = false ]]; do
    ...
done

ssh <host> 'sh -s' < second-step.sh
...
```

My question is: what condition should I check for in order to set `rebooted=true`? My idea was to try to connect via `ssh` until the command doesn't return an error anymore (and `sleep` for a bit in between attempts), but that seems quite rudimentary. Maybe it would be possible to send a message of the type "I've rebooted" from the remote machine and have the local one listen for it?

Comment: What is wrong with "rudimentary" if it works?

Comment: What is the pain point? That your script is working but ugly? You could try using `timeout` instead of `sleep` for a slightly more "elegant" script. If you intend to run this often/a lot debuggability could matter, as could edge cases, but for a one time thing, why bother? If you NEED it to be push based you could add a line in the root users `crontab` to include an `@reboot` command that would send the `uptime` to your endpoint but that may well be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: If you want to be _sure_ the reboot finished -- the Linux kernel has a "boot id" that's a unique UUID set every boot. Collect it before issuing the reboot, look at whether it changed after.

Comment: @ScottHunter, ...I'd worry about things that only _sometimes_ work. Depending on your exact network stack configuration/details, a service becoming transiently unavailable but then briefly reappearing before the system's "real" reboot is not particularly unrealistic -- say, if one network device goes down before another. It's more robust to avoid the assumption that a connectivity interruption can _only_ be the reboot taking place.

Comment: BTW, why are you running `sh` but tagging `bash`?

Comment: @Uberhumus this script is part of a hardware testing procedure for a lot of units, so I would like it to be as robust as possible. Could you detail the solution you've given in your comment?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm using `bash` on my local machine but `sh` on the remote one (more precisely `ash`, as part of OpenWRT). I've edited my post to make it more clear.

Comment: @dandan13, gladly! How would you like the rebooted machine to report back? Is it via SSH?

Comment: Also, @dandan13, please make sure that your `crontab` supports `@reboot` by running `man 5 crontab` and seeing if it is supported there.

Comment: @Uberhumus thanks! Yes, SSH seems the most straightforward, unless you have another suggestion.

Comment: @dandan13, see answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Linux kernel generates a unique, random identifier to reflect each system boot. (This has practical uses: for example, one can ask journald for logs generated during a specific boot session; so you may wish to record or retain it).

Collect the contents of `/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id` before issuing the reboot command.

*Only if it changes* to a different, non-empty value, consider the reboot complete.

Thus, one might end up with code looking like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
{
  initial_boot_id=$(ssh somehost 'cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id') &&
  [[ $initial_boot_id ]]
} || { echo 'Unable to collect initial boot id' >&2; exit 1; }

ssh somehost reboot

ok=0
for (( i=0; i<=30; i++ )); do
  if final_boot_id=$(ssh somehost 'cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id') &&
     [[ $final_boot_id ]] &&
     [[ $final_boot_id != "$initial_boot_id" ]]; then
    echo "Reboot complete" >&2
    ok=1
    break
  fi
done

if (( ! ok )); then
  echo "ERROR: Successful reboot not detected" >&2
  exit 1
fi

echo "System successfully rebooted" >&2
echo "${initial_boot_id} => ${final_boot_id}" >&2
exit 0
```

(Note that the above uses bashisms -- hence the `#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang instead of `#!/bin/sh`).

Comment: What about just using `uptime`?

Comment: That works too.

Comment: Should this be a "for" loop instead of "while."  for loop worked on my machine, but while got syntax error :)

Comment: @roger, ...fixed, ty. Not sure how I managed to miss that.

Answer (score 0):

The following is written with two assumptions:

1. Your version of `cron` supports the `@reboot` option.
2. The rebooted machine can SSH back to the "origin" machine, to push the information.

You could simply add to the `crontab` of a user that can `ssh` back to the origin machine:

```
@reboot <uptime -s >> ssh origin_host 'cat >> /var/log/last_time_machine_x_rebooted'
```

The method used to get the output of a local command to a remote server is taken from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/595713/append-a-local-file-to-a-remote-file-over-ssh) on Unix Stackexchange.

There is also an `scp` based option, that would look like:

```
@reboot uptime -s >> /var/log/last_time_machine_x_rebooted && scp /var/log/last_time_machine_x_rebooted origin_host:/var/log/last_time_machine_x_rebooted
```

Comment: OP's target is an embedded system; I wouldn't trust it to have cron installed _at all_, much less a particularly featureful version.

Comment: (Mind, I don't use cron even on new/modern/full-scale systems anymore; systemd timers do everything it can and more -- but those aren't relevant on most embedded targets either).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, interesting point, but specifically the OP is using OpenWRT. While I don't recall if `cron` is a default package on OpenWRT, I know [it can be installed](https://openwrt.org/packages/table/start?dataflt%5BName_pkg-dependencies*%7E%5D=cron) on it either with `opkg` (the default package manager for OpenWRT) or via `LuCi` (Its GUI). I don't know if this version has the `@reboot` option though.

Comment: Both anacron and fcron support `@reboot`, but I've never even heard of minicrond -- the name certainly implies that it's not going to go out of its way to be featureful.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, you are indeed correct, looking at [its source](https://github.com/openwrt/packages/blob/openwrt-21.02/utils/micrond/src/micrond.c), it does not have the `@reboot` option.

Comment: late to the convo, but I looked at whether OpenWRT's `cron` supports special strings; from what I [have](https://forum.openwrt.org/t/does-cron-support-reboot/169614) found it doesn't, but can be compiled to have it. I've tried it on my system (`@reboot touch /root/it-works`), but the command doesn't execute.

Comment: I've also looked at alternatives such as working with `/etc/rc.d`, but I haven't implemented something like this before. Extra info: I also have MQTT available, so I can post to topics using that (which would mean I can signal the reboot without having to create an extra file).